# How to align the products having long title in a single line in a widget? Can I add textoverflow attribute to it to solve it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

Products have long titles are wrapped but then the products are not getting aligned. Please [see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzCOE.jpg) for the clarity of my question. How can I solve this? Also, how can I use the text-overflow attribute in a widget to solve this?

Thank You
Sorry for the bad English

Comment: Please add html and css to your question to show the problem. We can see the problem in the picture but we do not want to write a full example. It will be easier to answer if the problem is shown in markup.

Comment: You'll probably want to do some research into css flex.